# Ubuntu 14.04 says insufficient memory in my /boot memory alocation while updating

Tags: ubuntu, boot, storage

I am new to Linux platform. I just tried installing Ubuntu alongside windows but allocated only **200 mb** to the /boot partition which is not recommended. Now Ubuntu software update keep on insists me no enough space. What should I do?

**This is my filesystem**

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda9        46G   15G   29G  33% /

none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

udev            892M  4.0K  892M   1% /dev

tmpfs           181M  1.4M  180M   1% /run

none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock

none            902M 1004K  902M   1% /run/shm

none            100M   68K  100M   1% /run/user

/dev/sda8        88M   67M   16M  82% /boot

Is there any way to increase my /boot partition without removing the total OS? Or should I completely uninstall Ubuntu and put it back?

Comment: Did you place /home on a separate partition? If you don't know, just [edit] your question to include the output of running `df -h` in a terminal.

Comment: Remove obsolete kernels.